# using block for command object close connection?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am a bit confused on the below coding. Are they both the same? If not, which one is the best and why?

```
//Two using blocks for Command and Connection
using (var cn = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
using (var cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, cn))
{
}


//One using block for Command and Connection
using (var cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, new OracleConnection(connectionString)))
{
}
```

Comment: It looks like you have an extra `)` after `sql` in both examples.

Comment: @juharr, I removed it. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First assuming that you accidently added an extra `)` (otherwise neither will even compile) then the first example will properly dispose of both the command and the connection where as the second will only dispose of the command.

Here is the equivalent code for the first.

```
OracleConnection cn = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
try
{
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, cn);
    try
    {
        // Use cmd and cn here.
    }
    finally
    {
        if(cmd != null)
            ((IDisposable)cmd).Dispose();
    }
}
finally
{
    if(cn != null)
        ((IDisposable)cn).Dispose();
}
```

and the second.

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, new OracleConnection(connectionString));
try
{
    // Use cmd here.
}
finally
{
    if(cmd != null)
        ((IDisposable)cmd).Dispose();
}
```

Also note that you can only create multiple instances that will all get disposed in one using if they are all the same type.  As the following example from the MSDN page about [using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) shows.

```
using (Font font3 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f),
            font4 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f))
{
    // Use font3 and font4.
}
```